# Using HTML Agility Pack to load all data into listboxes?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a page with 300-something rows and wanting to load them all into a list box, but different lists.

I want to put the date in one box, and the other 2 numbers in 2 other boxes also.

HTML ex:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>01/01/2017</td>
<td>100</td>
<td>500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>01/02/2017</td>
<td>200</td>
<td>400</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

My code that pulls this:

```
        private void LoadHTML()
    {
        int count = 0;
        var link = @"http://example.com/data";
        HtmlWeb Web = new HtmlWeb();
        var htmlDoc = Web.Load(link);
        var node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td");

        foreach (var x in node)
        {
            count = count + 1;
            if (count > 5)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(x.InnerText);
            }
        }
    }
```

listbox1 add's all the data from x, since everything is a td. tr would add each row, but I have nothing to split the data. The count after 5 is where my data starts. There is headers but I don't know how to pull the data from the specific headers in this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get a `tr` nodes.

Next, iterate it and get the `td` nodes.

```
var trNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

foreach (var tr in trNodes)
{
    var tdNodes = tr.SelectNodes("./td");

    listBox1.Items.Add(tdNodes[0].InnerText);
    listBox2.Items.Add(tdNodes[1].InnerText);
    listBox3.Items.Add(tdNodes[2].InnerText);
}
```